# Django Files and User interaction

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am doing a app for patients get their exams. Every user will have a file that only they can have access to. How can I do this link between User and File. I had created a model to represent the data of the exam

```
class Exames(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   patient = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   exame_pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title +" "+self.paciente
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding **get_queryset** function. Let say you're doing it in Django Admin and the user who access to django admin is patient.  It will filter exam based on user who access.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

...

@admin.register(Exam)
class ExamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.filter(patient=request.user)
        return queryset
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you make some changes to your model as follows, it will be easy to filter and authenticate based on user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Exames(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   exame_pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title +" "+self.patient
```

then in views you can override the queryset

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Exames.objects.filter(patient=self.request.user)
```